# How to escape the null character in here-document?(bash and/or dash)

Tags: bash, dash

I want to perform `shuf --zero-terminated` on multi-line strings with here-document.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a here-document in either of those shells. Shells are generally not good with nulls (except zsh). Why do you want a here-document specifically?

Comment: @MichaelHomer Because I can't pass the multi-line strings entity(i.e string include the newline character) to `shuf` as one single entity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here-documents in Bash and dash don't support this. You can't store a null in a variable, they are removed from command substitutions, you can't write one in literally, and you can't use ANSI-C quoting inside the here-document. Neither shell is null-friendly and they are generally treated as (C-style) string terminators if one does get in.

You have a few options: [use a real file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503687/73093), use zsh, use process substitution, or use standard input.

---

You *can* do exactly what you want in zsh, which is much more null-friendly.

```
zsh% null=$(printf '\x00')
zsh% hexdump -C <<EOT
heredoc> a${null}b${null}
heredoc> EOT
00000000  61 00 62 00 0a                                    |a.b..|
00000005
```

Note though that heredocs have an implicit terminating newline, which may not be desirable (it'll be an extra field for `shuf` after the final null).

---

For Bash, you can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) almost equivalently to your heredoc in combination with `printf` or `echo -e` to create nulls inline:

```
bash$ hexdump -C < <(
printf 'item 1\x00item\n2\x00'
)
00000000  69 74 65 6d 20 31 00 69  74 65 6d 0a 32 00        |item 1.item.2.|
0000000e
```

This is not necessarily entirely equivalent to a here-document, because those are often secretly put into real files by the shell (which matters for seekability, among other things).

Since you probably want to suppress terminating newlines, you can't even use a heredoc internally within the commands there - it has to be `printf`/`echo -ne` if safe to get fine-grained control over the output.

---

You can't do process substitution in dash, but in any shell you could pipe in standard input from a subshell:

```
dash$ (
printf 'item 1\x00'
printf 'item\n2\x00'
) | hexdump -C
00000000  69 74 65 6d 20 31 00 69  74 65 6d 0a 32 00        |item 1.item.2.|
0000000e
```

`shuf` is happy to read from standard input by default, so that should work for your concrete use case as I understand it. If you have a more complex command, being on the right-hand side of a pipeline can introduce some confounding elements with scoping.

---

Finally, you could write your data into a real file using `printf` and use that instead of a here-document. That option has been covered in [the other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503687/73093). You'll need to make sure you clean up the file afterwards, and may want to use [`mktemp`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) or similar if available to create a safe filename if there are any live security concerns.

Comment: Thank you, this is one elaborate answer, but lack [the simple script work in bash and dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503710/259284)

Answer (score 6):

Thank you all.
Let I post one answer base on you all and maybe best for me.

This script works nicely in bash and dash, no require real file or [process substitution in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution), no require an extra slow external program call, even you don't need to worry about any escape problem in entities as `%s` in [C printf](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/manpages-dev/printf.3.en.html), **but you should still take care to string escape in your shell itself**.

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s\0' "[tag1]
key1=value1
key2=value2
[/tag1]
" "[tag2]
key3=value3
key4=value4
[/tag2]
" | shuf --zero-terminated
#also see man printf(1)
```

For [`shuf`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/coreutils/shuf.1.en.html) only(not intent to general here-document alternative):

```
shuf --echo "[tag1]
key1=value1
key2=value2
[/tag1]" "[tag2]
key3=value3
key4=value4
[/tag2]"
```

Comment: Don't use `echo` for that, not even `/bin/echo` (on GNU systems for instance, whether `/bin/echo` supports `-e` depends on whether `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` is in the environment or not, on many other systems, `/bin/echo` doesn't support `-e` or `-n` or `\x00`). Use `printf '%s\0' 'first record' 'second record'... | shuf...`

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can do what you want in a heredoc. However it is trivial to do using `echo` as the following example shows:

```
$ cat demo
#!/bin/bash

echo -ne "one\0" > outfile
echo -ne "two\0" >> outfile
echo -ne "three\0" >> outfile

$ ./demo
$ od -a outfile
0000000   o   n   e nul   t   w   o nul   t   h   r   e   e nul
0000016
$
```

Comment: Thank you, but `echo` is not trivial, [see my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/503710/259284)

Comment: @fpmurphy In addition to Stephane's excellent comment on illiterate's answer, see also the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy.  If you do not like to use `echo`, simply use `printf`,

Comment: @fpmurphy, I do, of course. What I take issue with is that you're teaching *other* people to use `echo`, despite *`echo`'s own documentation* indicating that it's best avoided.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  There are millions of lines of shell code out there with `echo` statements and they work perfectly fine. The P in  POSIX stands for Portable and anything in the APPLICATION USAGE section is generally focused on portability issues.  If portability across multiple POSIX-compliant platforms and multiple shells, both old and modern, is required and `echo` is using `-n` as the first argument and escape sequences are used, then you have a case for not using `echo`. My example works OOTB in the two shells specified by the OP, i.e `bash` and 'dash`  You are tilting at windmills!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy.  Now to a side issue regarding the use of `printf` instead of `echo`.  Are you aware of the security risks of using applications and utilities that take variable argument lists? Security V portability? I will take security first and use `echo` where possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but bash's `printf` and C's `printf` are completely different things -- you don't have the vulnerabilities from C's legacy printf function in any shell implementation I'm aware of. And `dash -c 'echo -e foo'` prints `-e foo` with `-e` as part of the output (tested with dash 0.5.10.2), so the claim that the code here works in dash unmodified is simply false.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a "trick"

```
cat <<EOS | cat - <(echo -e "\0") | most
{
  "version":"1.1",
  "gelf-toekn":"SOMETHIN",
  "host": "api.ivsdev.net",
  "short_message": "foo",
   "full_message": "bar",
   "level": 1
}
EOS
```

The first heredoc cat is piped into a second one who concatenate it with a null byte.